# Pointing to base, converted to Derived Pointer

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, casting

Is it possible to get a base's derived class's type name by using `typeid( TYPE ).name()` ?

---

Example of pushing a base pointer back into a derived pointer, statically.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
class base 
{
public:
    virtual void known() = 0;
};

class derived: public base
{
public:
    void known() { std::cout << " I guess this means "; }
    void unknown(){ known(); std::cout << " its possible "; }
};

int main()
{
    derived d;

    std::cout << typeid( d ).name() << std::endl;
     // Prints out being a pointer to a derived class
    base* b = &d;

    std::cout << typeid( b ).name() << std::endl;
    // Prints out being a pointer to a base class
    // But how would you use it, or in any other way, 
    //get the original derived type name
    derived * db = (derived*) b; 
    // db is casted at at compile time, the derived class is known
    db->unknown();
}
```

Comment: Does `dynamic_cast` not do what you want?

Comment: No, that requires me to know exactly what the derived class is. Or so I read about it.

Comment: I think what you want is [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)?

Comment: @mpark not exactly. That requires it to be manually written down, meaning the classes have to be known before compile time.

Comment: C++ requires types to be known at compile time so it knows how to invoke the method. Without knowing that the type is `derived`, the compiler does not know that there is an `unknown` method, what parameters it accepts, or what it returns.

Comment: @RaymondChen I believe that is true. But, I forgot to mention that I actually planned on using `#include <typeinfo>` to merely get the name of the type, not the actual type itself. So I will reword my question

Comment: I think the second print statement was supposed to be `std::cout << typeid(b).name() << std::endl;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an expression whose type is a polymorphic base class, The result of the `typeid` operator refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the type of the most derived object.

**Example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class Base {
  public:

  virtual ~Base() {}

};  // Base

class Derived : public Base {};

int main() {
  Derived derived;
  /* By reference. */ {
    Base &base = derived;
    std::cout << typeid(base).name() << std::endl;
  }
  /* By pointer. */ {
    Base *base = &derived;
    std::cout << typeid(*base).name() << std::endl;
    // NOTE: typeid(base).name() results in printing of the Base class' name.
  }
}
```

Both cases above print the `Derived` class' name.

**References**

- [N3797](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf): `5.2.8` Type identification.
- [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid): 2) a)